# If you hate the question so much, why bring it back?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation, editing

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150266/is-c-too-hard

You keep editing it to bring back the question, yet insisted it be closed.

You won't let me delete it.

Ridiculous.

Comment: Why do you keep trying to hide the question?

Comment: Post closure is not a reason for vandalism, even if it's your own post.

Comment: Well, I guess you all need time to pat each other on the back and beat on Eddie some more for trying to bring something interesting to the place.  Have fun.

Answer (score 8):

Post vandalism is not allowed.

By posting on the site you cede certain rights to the post - see the [cc-by-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) link at the foot of every page.

Don't worry, the post <strike>will be</strike> has been deleted - but it will be deleted in the form you posted it, not the form you vandalised into.

Comment: Because it matters what something delete says. O_o

Comment: Has the question really been around for only a few minutes? If so, why not let the guy delete it in whatever state he prefers?

Comment: @CorbinMarch - I'm not allowed to delete it at all actually.  That's the REALLY absurd part.

Comment: @CrazyEddie - it's only locked for an hour to give you time to cool down.

Comment: @CorbinMarch just because it's not seen by *most* people is no reason to allow vandalism

Comment: @BenBrocka - I think this may be an example of principles getting in the way of good sense. Consider being a little flexible.

Comment: @CorbinMarch I fail to see the "good sense" in letting people vandalize posts just because they've been deleted. That content is still visible to some people and there's no "good sense" in turning a closed question's text into "You guys suck".

Comment: @BenBrocka - The "you guys suck" factor doesn't bother me. Who cares, right? Our skin is thicker than that, right? The "good sense" I'm talking about is being a little flexible as to when content is enshrined as Creative Commons-protected. It seems a little extreme to call an emotional edit to a short-lived question that's destined for the garbage bin vandalism. I don't see the harm in letting the guy blow off some steam.

Comment: @CorbinMarch I'm with you, and in general we _are_ more flexible, and just delete the question if the OP can't self delete and flags it asking for removal. However this isn't the first time we had this exact same discussion with Crazy Eddie. Flexibility, understanding and guidance for newer users is one thing, wasting our time with a user who has a long and colourful history of suspension worthy offences is another.

Comment: @CorbinMarch this is a site for questions and answers, not "blowing off steam". The typical forum crap of letting users do what they want is exactly what we try to avoid, especially when it involves abusive behavior toward other users.

Comment: @BenBrocka - I believe I understand the site's purpose. No need to condescend. I also believe that Crazy Eddie only became abusive after he felt attacked. A gentle and flexible response might have elicited a better result. I, for one, enjoy a site with differing opinions and strong personalities. I'd hate to chase away all of the users who don't agree with me.

Comment: @CorbinMarch - Don't worry about Crazy Eddie, he'll be back. Every site with a decent amount of traffic has their own version of Crazy Eddie. Some of them are really intelligent people who contribute great material, including Crazy Eddie. With that said, I think the main concern with the post vandalism is that deleted posts aren't really deleted. Anyone with 10k reputation can see them, and sometimes it's helpful to see the question in it's original state so it's clear *why* it was deleted.